# Spurious events in reputation calculation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

In my reputation summary I have this entry:

```
+40 / -32   23:29   8 events     Java Getter Methods - Best Practices
```

But when I look at the [answer itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491284/java-getter-methods-best-practices/9491365#9491365), it shows only two events, a single up and downvote (which I believe to be the correct set of events).

I also noticed that my rep was probably adjusted by -8 recently, which could be linked to this. Although in that case the adjustment overshot the correct magnitude by 2.

Answer (score 4):

A user reversed their vote many times, so over the duration, your rep did in fact change many times, we may look at rolling these up, but it is accurate right now.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I hope they made their minds up, cos this would be a great way to reduce someone's rep to 0 :)